# Removing Dates from a CSV file

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

I have a huge list of tweets but I want to remove a lot of them before a certain date. I think I need to use sed, awk, or grep to remove these guys but I am not sure on the syntax. The format for this is in the second column in the form of "2017-9-18 XX:XX:XX" and say I wanted to remove the tweets before 2017-9-15".

Thanks a ton guys!

Comment: You could just open in a spreadsheet app like LibreOffice Calc, then select and delete the bits you don't want.

Comment: Please give us a sample data to see both how it is and how it should be!

Comment: Are the tweets sorted by date? Is it okay to sort them?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dategrep`. From `perldoc /usr/local/bin/dategrep`:

```
NAME
    dategrep - print lines matching a date range

SYNOPSIS
      dategrep --start "12:00" --end "12:15" --format "%b %d %H:%M:%S" syslog
      dategrep --end "12:15" --format "%b %d %H:%M:%S" syslog
      dategrep --last-minutes 5 --format "%b %d %H:%M:%S" syslog
      dategrep --last-minutes 5 --format rsyslog syslog
      cat syslog | dategrep --end "12:15"

DESCRIPTION
    Do you even remember how often in your life you needed to find lines in a
    log file falling in a date range? And how often you build brittle regexs
    in grep to match entries spanning over a hour change?

    dategrep hopes to solve this problem once and for all.
```

...

```
INSTALLATION
    It is possible to install this script via perl normal install routines.

      perl Makefile.PL && make && make install

    Or via CPAN:

      cpan App::dategrep

    You can also install one of the two prebuild versions, which already
    include all or some of dategrep's dependencies. Which to choose mainly
    depends on how hard it is for you to install Date::Manip. The small
    version is just 22.3KB big and includes all libraries except Date::Manip.
    The big one packs everything in a nice, neat package for you, but will
    cost you almost 10MB of disk space. Both are always included in the latest
    release <https://github.com/mdom/dategrep/releases/latest>.

    So, to install the big version you could just type:

      wget -O /usr/local/bin/dategrep https://github.com/mdom/dategrep/releases/download/v0.58/dategrep-standalone-big
      chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dategrep

    And for the small one (with the apt-get for Debian):

      apt-get install libdate-manip-perl
      wget -O /usr/local/bin/dategrep https://github.com/mdom/dategrep/releases/download/v0.58/dategrep-standalone-small
      chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dategrep
```

Comment: This looks good but my laptop just crashed so I'll have to check it out in a bit!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions make this a simple problem. The first version outputs dates on or after 2017-9-01.

```
grep -E "2017-([9]|[0-1][0-9])" file > output_file
```

This second example further filters the output to exclude dates before 2017-9-15. But only if the day of the month is zero padded.

```
grep -E "2017-([9]|[0-1][0-9])-([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])" file | grep -Ev "2017-9-(0[0-9]|[0-1][0-5])" > output_file
```

Each pair of square brackets represents a single digit. The `|` character means or in regex. See [Bash Guide for Beginners Chapter 4. Regular expressions](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_04.html) for further details.