# How to check user log details from x month to y month?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, login

If I was logged into my user account, then how can I check the login details such as date, time etc using terminal?
Also please tell me, if I want to check the log details of the previous month or year or from x month to y month etc.

Comment: hello Sergiy, thank you for your attention and edit. Actually what I meant was to check the log details from a certain period of time such as from x month to y month or of the previous year like that.

Comment: Could you please notify me in the comments when this question is reopened? I’ll write a proper answer based on https://askubuntu.com/a/959078/175814 and/or https://gist.github.com/davidfoerster/c35afe1c62f1468205a6f56b0cb9b44b.

Answer (score 2):

`last` command will help you to see user logins and restarts.

[image]

`cat /var/log/auth.log | grep session` command will give you more details.

[image]

Comment: can I get the details by giving from and to?

Comment: @SRJ577 There is an answer to that but I think you will have to ask a separate question as this one has been locked down as a duplicate with an answer (which doesn't include your supplementary)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux system there is folder `/var/log` where all system generated log files get saved. 
You can use this by

```
tail /var/log/auth.log  
tail /var/log/syslogs
```

You can also use command `w` to get login details.